# Rails 5- jQuery works in local production(rails s -e production) but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I can run jQuery on local production doing `rails s -e production` but when the same project is deployed to Heroku, jQuery doesn't work and I get an error in the console that says

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

. I am not using Turbolinks so I don't think I need to do anything besides

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
//everything js goes here });
```

Normal JavaScript works though.

I checked in the console on Chrome with `$("#element-id")` and it gave details of the element, so I think jQuery is being loaded. Or is it that Chrome console has jQuery by default?

My application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require Chart.min
//= require_tree .
```

Shouldn't the local production environment be the same as the Heroku? Why is the behavior different on Heroku and local production environment?

Comment: Is jquery uncommented in your gemfile?  You need to add it explicity now that it is no longer included by default in rails 5 and then run 'bundle install'

Comment: No, I have 'jquery-rails' in my gemfile